# How to set the height of the body equals to the length of an array in Angular

Tags: angularjs

I have this user list, which can grow dynamically if you add a new user. Now I want my whole body to be the length of the user list.

In my factory I determine the length of the array and now I need to know how to access/translate this to the view in angular. Something like this:

```
<div class="mainWrapper" id="mainView" style="width: {{gridSizeNG.x * 122}}px; height: {{gridSizeNG.y *  the length of the user list }}">

...

</div>
```

Part of my factory code:

```
UserService.getUsers = function () {
        $http.get("api/users") //your API url goes here
            .success(function(dataFromServer){
                //console.log('LOGGING DATADROMSERVER ', dataFromServer);
                //UserService.userList = [];

                /*dataFromServer.forEach(function(user, index, arr) { 
                    UserService.userList.push(user); 
                })*/
                var initials = function(name){
                    var d1 = name.split(" ")[0].charAt(0).toUpperCase();
                    var d2;
                    try
                    {
                        d2 = name.split(" ")[1].charAt(0).toUpperCase();
                    }
                    catch(e){
                        d2 = "";
                    }

                    return  d1 + d2;
                    console.log('LOGGING INITIALS ', d1 + d2);
                }    

                for (var i = 0; i < dataFromServer.length; i++) {
                    UserService.userList[i] = dataFromServer[i];

                    UserService.userList[i].initials = initials(UserService.userList[i].name)                    
                };

                console.log('#### logging lenght of the userlist ' , UserService.userList.length );

                //here you should update the usersList from the server like this:
                //UserService.usersList = dataFromServer;

                return dataFromServer;
            })
            .error(function(errorFromServer){
            //something went wrong, process the error here
                console.log("Error in getting the users from the server");
            })
        };

      return UserService;
    })
```

As you can see from the image, the height of the body is now not dynamic 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

IMO the best approach here would be to use CSS to your advantage and have the size grow in accordance with the amount of elements you have. Which means (idealy) you don't need to set the height and width property in CSS, you only need to set the max-height and max-width properties, should the list grow more than the body.

If you do want to control the height and width using JS then use [ng-style](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle) instead of style, keep in mind ng-style is considered a last resort in controlling styles, one should ideally use [ng-class](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) if possible.

With ng-style you will be able to use your scope variables to control the height and width.

Also try to use something like this, using your existing html code:

```
<div class="mainWrapper" id="mainView" style="width: {{gridSizeNG.x}} * 122 + 'px'; height: {{gridSizeNG.y}} * {{the length of the user list }} + 'px'">

...

</div>
```

Not sure if the above code will work, but ng-style will.